# How to make if condition in dropdown

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I am trying to make a Django based website, and I want to make a dropdown with if and else conditions working on it, means that if a person selects physics in the dropdown and presses the submit button, it should go to a specific page and if he presses chemistry then it goes to a specific page, please tell me how to do this, I am attaching my code.

Main page (home.html):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hi there</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{% url 'test' %}">
        <select name="Subject">
            <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
            <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
            <option value="Chemistry">chemistry</option>
            <option value="accounts">accounts</option>
            <option value="bsuiness">business</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Generate Password" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Views.py:

```html
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'homepage/home.html')

def test(request):
    if request.GET.get('Physics'):
        return render(request, 'homepage/home.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'homepage/test2.html')
```

urls.py

```html
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from homepage import views as home_views
from homepage import views as test_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_views.home, name='home'),
    path('test/', test_views.test, name='test'),
```

**Please help by telling what to code to make the if statement work**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add if statement to your django code
Django's backend framework which means you can't do any dinamic change on page.

button generate link 
1)https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

then make more  pages and root them
2)https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/topics/http/urls/

Before Django please try make a webpage on HTML + CSS + Js

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is capture the GET/POST request (that you send with your form submit button) in Django, then you get the dropdown parameter and then based on that condition, you can decide which webpage on which url Django will serve.

Then on the client side you have to handle going to the url that you decided to serve with Django.`(This can be done with javascript)`

Comment: I am new to Django and al coding stuff, so it would be really amazing if you could tell me how to do this with java script